# Import AAR in Flutter project

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, aar

From my previous project, I exported a module as an AAR file.
Now, I would like to import it into the Flutter project.
I found a guide that says to import as a Module
`File > New > New Module` but there is no way to do this.
Please could someone help me?